# Gridview elements alignment

Tags: android, gridview, android-imageview, textview

The screenshot of my present design

[image]

But I wanted the design to be something like the design below

[image]

**The grid layout is as below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Single gridview element layout is as below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/im" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="23"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:textSize="12sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="@string/im" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="23"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="12sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It will scroll in single line

Comment: Actually i thought of this but didn't tell kiran 
ask kiran

Comment: That worked, but i want to display the whole thing. It is displaying like continuation (College Registra...). I want to display whole thing if not in a single line, in two lines.

Comment: But what about the first question ? Expansion of images to whole screen as the image i have put.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxLength="23"
    android:padding="10dp"
   android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="12sp" >
</TextView>
```

```
Try this in your row layout
```

Comment: That worked fine but some long texts are actually hidden behind the images. I will add new image . Give me a second.

Comment: I have added new image onto my question in the end , have a look.

Comment: Nope still the same output. Text is hidden behind the next row image.

Comment: Can you try removing margin between image and text?

Comment: android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
Remove this line Clean project and run

Comment: Ohh than try 
android:singleLine="true"

Comment: Wait after doing all the things suggested it is displaying like the image i updated now.

Comment: put this and if not working you have to replace ImageView with drawableTop in TextView